# Preventing for loop from exceeding condition in PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

How to prevent for loop from exceeding condition?
Loop below returns 25. I want it to return 20.

```
for ($i = 5; $sum < 23;)
{
    echo $sum += $i;
}
```

This loop is just an example. There will be variables with any value in place of 5 and 23

Comment: Can you give a bit more information? What's the point of your loop, input, output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your loop differently.

A `for` loop is designed to run until the conditions evaluates `false`. In your case, the loop at `sum = 20` will still run, becuase `sum < 23` evaluates to `true`. So if you want 20, simply write `$sum < 20`.

Or if I give it a second thought, you may want to do it like that:

```
<?PHP
    $sum = 0;

    for($i = 5; ($sum+$i) < 23;)
    {
        $sum += $i;
    }

    echo $sum;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Very simple solution.